# Why am I getting an error with pip install google.colab?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I just installed the newest version of Python and created a virtual environment before trying to install Google Colab. This is the code and error I am getting

```
(nyc) michellemarji@michelles-MBP ~ % pip install google.colab --use-pep517
Collecting google.colab
  Using cached google-colab-1.0.0.tar.gz (72 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Collecting google-auth~=1.4.0 (from google.colab)
  Using cached google_auth-1.4.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (64 kB)
Collecting ipykernel~=4.6.0 (from google.colab)
  Using cached ipykernel-4.6.1-py3-none-any.whl (104 kB)
Collecting ipython~=5.5.0 (from google.colab)
  Using cached ipython-5.5.0-py3-none-any.whl (758 kB)
Collecting notebook~=5.2.0 (from google.colab)
  Using cached notebook-5.2.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (8.0 MB)
Collecting six~=1.12.0 (from google.colab)
  Using cached six-1.12.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (10 kB)
Collecting pandas~=0.24.0 (from google.colab)
  Using cached pandas-0.24.2.tar.gz (11.8 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Installing backend dependencies ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [5 lines of output]
      <string>:435: DeprecationWarning: distutils Version classes are deprecated. Use packaging.version instead.
      <string>:436: DeprecationWarning: distutils Version classes are deprecated. Use packaging.version instead.
      error in pandas setup command: 'install_requires' must be a string or list of strings containing valid project/version requirement specifiers; Expected end or semicolon (after version specifier)
          pytz >= 2011k
               ~~~~~~~^
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

I tried upgrading pip and that did not work.